# Is there a way to get exception by framework if the exception is not throwed out?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

If an exception happens, and it's caught in catch block, but is not throwed out. Is there a way for the framework to know that there's an exception?

Background(why): We have to remake a previous project and add Exception Process. However, many exceptions are not throwed out.

Thanks very much!

```
//for example
private void handle() {
    try{
        int i = 5/0;
    }catch(Throwable e){
        ;//here the e is not throwed
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess no, unless the framework has come means to redefine its behaviour when the exception is caught.

Comment: Why don't you catch `ArithmeticException`? It's bad practice to catch `Throwable`.

Comment: Nopes. Sorry. No can do. But what you can do is give the original author a kick in the a** for writing poor code.

Answer (score 1):

This would perhaps be achievable, but not without hacking. For example you could use AspectJ to advise the `Throwable` constructors with code which will register the event of exception instantiation. This is not the same as actually throwing them, but it's a good approximation. The key advantage is that with this approach you have only one place where you intervene.

Note that you will definitely get a lot of noise with this approach since exceptions are legitimately thrown and caught locally in many places, including the JDK itself.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I would make a try.